# OpenStreetMap/or AnyOtherMap - how to print location JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Lets just say my location is 38.5312/-28.5219.

Which map should I use, and which would be easiest way to print a picture (any format) and it having take certain zoom viewing (2kms left right/up down) and that it is displayed in 500px X 500px. But these are not important and fixed.

Question is: Does anyone how can i get graphical representation of a location in a image? With/without marker.

Any help would be appreciated.

(JAVASCRIPT)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [Google Map Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps) ?

Your image should be :

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=38.5312,-28.5219&size=500x500&zoom=10" width="500" height="500">
```

Comment: It doesnt work for some reason.  But How do i give that lat and lng and zoom 20 to be saved as picture. Does Openstreetmap or Google provide that?

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how to easyly display an image in your HTML.

Comment: I want to print it on my printer. AKA want to save it as PDF/JPG.

Comment: Oh ^^ right click on the image and do what you want !!

Comment: Thank you. however I cannot use google maps cause of their tracking and more. is it possible to do something with openstreetmaps Karbos?

Answer (score 0):

Open Street Map does not provide static images in my knowledge, but you could try [Leaflet API](http://leafletjs.com) (Open Street Map Wrapper) and [Leaftlet EasyPrint Plugin](https://github.com/rowanwins/leaflet-easyPrint)

```
npm install leaflet
npm install leaflet-easyprint
```

Your HTML template will just contain an empty div with an id ("mapId", for example) and then your bootstrap Javascript will look like this :

```
var map = L.map('mapId').setView([38.5312,-28.5219], 10); 
L.easyPrint({
  title: 'Print map',
  position: 'bottomright',
  sizeModes: ['A4Portrait', 'A4Landscape']
}).addTo(map);
```